# Using CONNECT BY to get all parents and one child in Hierarchy through SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I was going through some previous posts on CONNECT BY usage. What I need to find is that what to do if I want to get all the parents (i.e, up to root) and just one child for a node, say 4.

It seems Like I will have to use union of the following two:-

```
 SELECT  * 
 FROM    hierarchy 
 START WITH id = 4
 CONNECT BY id = PRIOR parent
union
     SELECT  *
     FROM    hierarchy
     WHERE LEVEL =<2
     START WITH
     id = 4
     CONNECT BY
     parent = PRIOR id
```

Is there a better way to do this, some workaround that is more optimized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a sub-select (and `DISTINCT`) to find all children of `4`:

```
Select Distinct *
From hierarchy
Start With id In ( Select id
                   From hierarchy
                   Where parent = 4 )
Connect By id = Prior parent
```

Using `UNION` you could at least remove the `CONNECT BY` from your second query:

```
  Select *
  From hierarchy
  Start With id = 4
  Connect By id = Prior parent
Union
  Select *
  From hierarchy
  Where parent = 4
```

---

Never use `SELECT *`, always name the columns you actually need. This makes your query easier to read, to maintain and to optimize.

Comment: Its sometimes really funny when we overlook some obvious things. The union part was SO obvious but I think I was too much preoccupied with the CONNECT BY clause. And yes, I know not to use SELECT * but was just trying to shorten the text. :)
Thanks.